# Cuda matrix multiplication results differs from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cuda, matrix-multiplication

Its been two days and I am still cant figure it out why my implementation of CUDA matrix multiplication differs from the results produced in MATLAB.

CUDA kernel: A(200x60000) = W(200x784) * Data(784x6000)

```
__global__ void CalculateA(Matrix W, Matrix Data, Matrix A)
{
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ((Row < W.row) && (Col < Data.col)){ 
        float Cvalue = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < W.col; ++i){
            Cvalue += W.elements[Row*W.col+i] * Data.elements[i*Data.col+Col];
        }
    A.elements[Row*A.col+Col] = Cvalue;
    }
}
```

And calling the kernel:

```
 void myFunc(Matrix W1, Matrix data){
        Matrix d_W1, d_data, d_a2, a2;
    size_t size;

    a2.row = W1.row;    d_a2.row = a2.row;
    a2.col = data.col;  d_a2.col = a2.col;
    size = a2.col*a2.row*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_a2.elements,size);

    d_W1.row = W1.row;  d_W1.col = W1.col;
    size = W1.col*W1.row*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_W1.elements,size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_W1.elements,W1.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    d_data.col = data.col; d_data.row = data.row;
    size = data.row*data.col*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_data.elements,size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data.elements,data.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 dimGrid(data.col/32 + 1, W1.row/32 + 1, 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(32, 32, 1);

    CalculateA<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_W1, d_data, d_a2);
    a2.elements = new float [a2.row*a2.col];
    cudaMemcpy(a2.elements,d_a2.elements,sizeof(float)*a2.row*a2.col,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\nA2 first and last member %f - %f\n",a2.elements[0],a2.elements[a2.row*a2.col-1]);
}
```

Results difference is not low for example first and last elements of CUDA code is 0.011322 and -0.179534 but multiplying in MATLAB results in 0.4280 and 0.0056.

this is how I do it in MATLAB:

```
>> size(W1)     ans =       200   784

>> size(data)   ans =       784       60000

>> z2=W1*data;

>> size(z2)     ans =       200       60000

>> z2 = z2(:);

>> z2(1)        ans =   0.4280

>> z2(200*60000)ans =  0.0056
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question? (And you do know that Matlab performs all floating point computations in double precision by default?=

Comment: Well my question is how to reproduce MATLAB results using CUDA, and yes I saved my mat files after converting them to single precision.

Comment: Try starting with something simple, like the matrix multiplication of two scalars and then two 2x2 matrices and work your way up from there. If you already get stuck on the small matrix, observe each intermediate result and hopefully that, combined with the input matrices, will dig up the error.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin thanks dude, using small test case revealed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. If I expand your kernel and function into a complete running example like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Matrix
{
    int row;
    int col;
    float *elements;

    __device__ __host__
    float& operator()(int r, int c) { return elements[r*col + c]; };
};

__global__ void CalculateA(Matrix W, Matrix Data, Matrix A)
{
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ((Row < W.row) && (Col < Data.col)){ 
        float Cvalue = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < W.col; ++i){
            Cvalue += W.elements[Row*W.col+i] * Data.elements[i*Data.col+Col];
        }
    A.elements[Row*A.col+Col] = Cvalue;
    }
} 

void myFunc(Matrix W1, Matrix data)
{
    Matrix d_W1, d_data, d_a2, a2;
    size_t size;

    a2.row = W1.row;    d_a2.row = a2.row;
    a2.col = data.col;  d_a2.col = a2.col;
    size = a2.col*a2.row*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_a2.elements,size);

    d_W1.row = W1.row;  d_W1.col = W1.col;
    size = W1.col*W1.row*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_W1.elements,size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_W1.elements,W1.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    d_data.col = data.col; d_data.row = data.row;
    size = data.row*data.col*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_data.elements,size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data.elements,data.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 dimGrid(data.col/32 + 1, W1.row/32 + 1, 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(32, 32, 1);

    CalculateA<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_W1, d_data, d_a2);
    a2.elements = new float [a2.row*a2.col];
    cudaMemcpy(a2.elements,d_a2.elements,sizeof(float)*a2.row*a2.col,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int j=0; j<a2.col; ++j) {
        for(int i=0; i<a2.row; ++i) {
            std::cout << a2(i,j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    float a[6] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f };
    float b[6] = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f};

    Matrix W1; W1.row=2; W1.col=3; W1.elements = &a[0];
    Matrix Data; Data.row=3; Data.col=2; Data.elements = &b[0];

    myFunc(W1, Data);

    return 0;
}
```

and run it, I get this:

```
>nvcc -arch=sm_21 -Xptxas="-v" -m32 matrix.cu
matrix.cu
tmpxft_000014f4_00000000-5_matrix.cudafe1.gpu
tmpxft_000014f4_00000000-10_matrix.cudafe2.gpu
matrix.cu
ptxas : info : 132 bytes gmem, 28 bytes cmem[14]
ptxas : info : Compiling entry function '_Z10CalculateA6MatrixS_S_' for 'sm_21'
ptxas : info : Function properties for _Z10CalculateA6MatrixS_S_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas : info : Used 14 registers, 68 bytes cmem[0]
tmpxft_000014f4_00000000-5_matrix.cudafe1.cpp
tmpxft_000014f4_00000000-15_matrix.ii

>cuda-memcheck a.exe
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
2.2 4.9
2.8 6.4
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

which is the correct answer for the dot product assuming column major ordering (which is the Matlab convention).

So if your results don't agree, it is because of something you haven't shown us. One likelihood is that your test problem is so large (and kernel so inefficient) that if you are running this on a display GPU, your program is hitting the display driver watchdog timer limit and being killed before the kernel finishes running. Also note that you have *no* CUDA API error checking whatsoever, so it is possible that you are getting runtime errors which is either stopping your kernel from finishing or even running at all, but you simply don't notice because of the lack of error checking.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was reading mat file, i was reading [1 2 3; 4 5 6] as 1,4,2,5,3,6. Actually i am using Matio lib to read mat files so i just saved transpose of matrix in Matlab and change row and columns variable and got the right answer. Just wondering if there is better way to read it. this is the line i use to read the mat file:
    memcpy(matrix.elements, matvar -> data, matvar -> nbytes);

Comment: @Th3_c0d3r: If this answered you question, please consider accepting it to get this question off the unanswered list. I can't really help you in suggesting better ways to do something when I haven't seen the code in question, and in any case it doesn't sound like anything to do with CUDA programming, which puts it outside of the scope of this question anyway.